# Get mounted volumes list with Swift?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, mounted-volumes

Does anyone know how to get a list of all removable volumes mounted with Swift?

I've already tried this, but it return a list of all files and subfolders of external drivers:

```
let filemanager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath("/Volumes")

while let file = files?.nextObject() {
    println(file)
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: file as! String, action: Selector(""), keyEquivalent: ""))
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This prints the list of all mounted volumes:

```
let filemanager = NSFileManager()
let keys = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey]
let paths = filemanager.mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: nil)
if let urls = paths as? [NSURL] {
    for url in urls {
        println(url)
    }
}
```

You can of course filter to get only the paths inside the "Volumes" directory:

```
let filemanager = NSFileManager()
let keys = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey]
let paths = filemanager.mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: nil)
if let urls = paths as? [NSURL] {
    for url in urls {
        if url.relativePath?.pathComponents.count > 1 {
            if url.relativePath?.pathComponents[1] == "Volumes" {
                println(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And with Swift 2 there's two differences: pass `[]` instead of `nil` for the filemanager's options, and there's no need to cast the array of NSURLs:

```
let filemanager = NSFileManager()
let keys = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey]
let paths = filemanager.mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: [])
if let urls = paths {
    for url in urls {
        if url.relativePath?.pathComponents.count > 1 {
            if url.relativePath?.pathComponents[1] == "Volumes" {
                print(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 2.1**

```
let keys = [NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, NSURLVolumeIsEjectableKey]
let paths = NSFileManager().mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(keys, options: [])
if let urls = paths {
    for url in urls {
        if let components = url.pathComponents
            where components.count > 1
            && components[1] == "Volumes" {
                print(url)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 3**

```
let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [.volumeNameKey, .volumeIsRemovableKey, .volumeIsEjectableKey]
let paths = FileManager().mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: keys, options: [])
if let urls = paths {
    for url in urls {
        let components = url.pathComponents
        if components.count > 1
           && components[1] == "Volumes"
        {
            print(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, perfect, but how can remove the 'Optional("' in front of the text?

Comment: Use `if let` to unwrap the value. Where do you get an Optional? I'll update my answer if necessary.

Comment: can you post an example? i get 'Optional("NAME")

Comment: Yes of course, but I need to know where do you get an Optional, because I don't: when I run this code the results are not optionals. Do you get the `url` as an Optional where we print it, or is it something else? Is it with Swift 1 or Swift2?

Comment: Ok, no problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: It's recommended to use `FileManager.default` rather than 'FileManager()`

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems a filesystem object with a system file number of 2 is a mount, regardless of a remote (nfs, smb, afp) or a local mount.

Here's an example:

```
let path = "/System/Volumes/Preboot"
let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: String(describing: path))
if let fileSystemFileNumber = systemAttributes[.systemFileNumber] as? NSNumber {
    print("System File Number: \(fileSystemFileNumber)")
}
```

So maybe this could be a short way to find mounts

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [
    .volumeNameKey,
    .volumeIsRemovableKey,
    .volumeIsEjectableKey,
    .volumeAvailableCapacityKey,
    .volumeTotalCapacityKey,
    .volumeUUIDStringKey,
    .volumeIsBrowsableKey,
    .volumeIsLocalKey,
    .isVolumeKey,
]

let manager = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: keys)
if let urls = manager {
    print(urls)
}
```

This code is working fine for MacOS, however on the iOS side it always returns nil. Is there any known workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Please, format your code right and remove extra spaces :)